# Exercise on method call in class hierarchy

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem about method calls in Java that seems really strange, I hope someone can help about it.
Here it is the code of the three classes, A is the top class with C inheriting from A and D inheriting from C.

```
class A {
    int f(double x) {
        return 1;
    }

    int f(boolean x) {
        return 2;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    int f(double x) {
        return 3;
    }

    int f(int x) {
        return 4;
    }
} 

class D extends C {
    int f(double x) {
        return 5;
    }   

    int f(int x) {
        return 6;
    }

} 

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C b = new D();
        A d = new D();

        System.out.println(b.f(33));
        System.out.println(d.f(33));
    }
}
```

When I call method of object b with an int I get 6, which means that the method f(int x) from class D is called. But when I call the same method on object d I get 5, which means that the method f(double x) from class D is called. Why does it behave like that? Why an integer is considered an integer in one case and a double in the other? It is something related to how I declared the two objects but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the type of the objects. `b`'s reference is of type `C` and `d`'s reference is of type `A`. In cases of inheritance, the JVM binds the methods at run-time, meaning that you can only call methods of the reference type, but the overridden method is the one that will run.

When you call the function on `d`, the JVM automatically casts to a `double` because `A` has no corresponding method for an `int` argument. Then, the method trickles down to `D` because the object is an instance of `D`, but it still trickles down as a `double`.